# Selenium Python - Select the latest text field

Tags: python, selenium

I have a web form that has a vertical row of fields, and I need to insert a text in the last one. Thing is, I'm not sure how to get the last one.

[Here's an image showing the form, along with the inspect element for the last row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVITI.png)

Currently, this is what I have:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="address259"]').send_keys(username)
```

Problem is, it only works because I manually put in the current last value (which is address250)

In selenium, is it possible to get the last text field? As seen in the image, the current last field has the value of `name/id` equal to `address259`

Comment: The id/name of the elements, is always `address259` ? Or does it change. If it does not change, have you tried to find element by `id` or `name`.

Comment: I think the attribute `placeholder = "Address"` is unique. Try using that in the xpath.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @pmadhu - it keeps adding up (257,258,259, and so on...). That's really good thinking! I've tried that but unfortunately it still does the first text field.

Comment: Now that I think of it, it really just needs to put it in a blank text field. Thing is, I wasn't able to get a list of all the text fields. If I were able to do so, maybe I could loop through it and insert it into the empty ones. For some reason the following doesn't work `a = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input"]')
print(a)`. It returns nothing

Comment: you can always use `find_elements_by_xpath` with char `s` in word `elements` to get list with all elements and later use `[-1]` to get last element from list.

Comment: you could first get all `div` with class `form-control repeate` to get all rows and later get last row using `[-1]` - `last_row = all_rows[-1]`and later use another `xpath` with `last_row` instead of `driver` to search `input` only in this row.

Comment: @furas The XPATH I mentioned only gets one. Do you happen to know how should I call the xpath to get all the text fields?

Comment: you have to use `find_elements_by_xpath` with char `s` in word `elements` - and you get list with all elements

Comment: @furas Yes! That's it! It worked! Just one last thing, is it possible to have it test if the field s empty? AKA if that particular textbox is equal to ""?

Comment: Selenium has `.text` to get text from element - `driver.find_element_by_xpath(..).text` - but I don't remeber if it works with `input` - maybe it needs to get `value`. You may also try `xpath` with `//input[text() = ""]` but I didn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

Could not comment this long, so answering it.

The `class-name` has a space in it, may be thats the issue.

Try with below xpaths once:

```
//input[@placeholder = 'Address']
//input[contains(@class,'form-control') and @placeholder = 'Address']
//input[starts-with(@class,'form-control') and @placeholder = 'Address']
//input[contains(@class,'ui-autocomplete-input') and @placeholder = 'Address']
//input[ends-with(@class,'ui-autocomplete-input') and @placeholder = 'Address']
```

See if any of the xpaths matches the element with 1/1.
And also apply some Explicit waits and try.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Unfortunately, all the text rows have `placeholder="Address"`. When I ran it, it only returned the first text field. It putted the IP in the first one.

Comment: It's a really hard task since even though the new text field is empty, in HTML, the field has `value=129.211.14.48`, which is the IP of the previous text field.. Beginning to think this is impossible because of this.